# Single docker container slightly outperforming its host in cpu performance: Why?

Tags: docker

I ran an experiment to compare the CPU performance of a docker container against the CPU performance of the host it is running on.

**Cases**

**A**: Benchmark program run on Host machine (Intel i5, 2.6 GHz, 2 processors, 2 cores)
**B**: Benchmark program run on Docker container running on the same host machine.
(No resource limiting is done for container in B. i.e. container has all 1024 cpu shares for itself. No other container is running)

**Benchmark program: Numerical Integration**

Numerical Integration: is a standard example of a massively parallel program. A standard numerical integration [example program](https://gist.github.com/pramttl/d860d4f33e91ae1f5a6a) written in C++ using OpenMP lib is taken (which has already been tested for correctness). The program is run 11 times by varying number of available threads within the program from 1-11. These 11 runs are done for each case A and B. So a total of 22 runs are done 11 for host and 11 for container.

X axis: Number of threads available in the program

Y axis:  indicates performance which is inverse of time (Calculated by multiplying inverse of time to run program, with a constant).

**Result**
[image]

**Observation**

The docker container running on host is slightly outperforming the host machine. This experiment was repeated 4-5 times across 2 different hosts and **every** time the container performance curve was slightly above host performance curve.

**Question**

How is the container performance higher than the host machine when the docker container is running on the host itself?

Possible Reason: Higher priority of of the docker cgroup processes?

I am hypothesizing that the processes within the container's cgroup, might be getting a higher process priority leading to a higher performance of the program running within the container as compared to when the program directly runs on the host machine. Does this sound like a possible explanation?

Comment: How are you determining the time? What OS is thist. What compiler. What compiler options.  I'm a little surprised you see so much of an improvement after 2 threads since you only have two physical cores and HT is usually not so effective.

Comment: Looking at the code it appears you are using `omp_get_wtime()`. That's good.

Comment: @Zboson: My bad, I typed 2 cores and HT-2 in confusion. It is 2 processors and 2 cores. Updated that in question now. Also OS is:  Ubuntu 14.04. Compiler is g++ with -fopenmp option

Comment: Intriguing, and not what I expected. My only thought might be that the docker container is 'cleaner' do not doing annoying things like on-access virus checking or similar....

Comment: What is the thread topology? Thread1 runs on processor1 and thread2 runs on processor2  or Thread1 and Thread2 run on processor1 and thread3 and thread4 run on processor2?

Comment: Is there a difference between the compiler or OpenMP version/configuration on the host v.s. the one in the docker image? Seeing that you compile the program using the driver program for each run, that might be a source of optimization differences.

Comment: @Zboson: I am not sure about the thread topology. Nothing is specified about how the threads use the processor in the program link I used [1]. It should be whatever is the default. I don't know how to check it.
 [1], https://gist.github.com/pramttl/d860d4f33e91ae1f5a6a

Comment: @miraculixx: Interesting point. I didn't take a note of this when I ran the experiment. GCC version was 5.3.0 on host, 4.8.4 on docker. I'll rerun experiment after updating gcc on docker. But, If docker has older version of gcc it is likely to be less optimized than host and yet it performs better so that is still intriguing; I should still match versions and re-run experiment to rule this out as a possibility.

Comment: What optimization compiler option are you using? From your code I see `g++ -fopenmp -DNUMS=14000 -DNUMT=%s numeric_integration.cpp `. I really hope that's not what you're using as I don't see any optimization level defined (I would use `-O3`). It's rather pointless to discuss performance without optimization enabled.

Comment: If you're not compiling with optimization enabled then you have probably discovered that gcc 4.84 without optimization is faster than gcc 5.3.0 (in your case) without optimization. I would not be surprised by that and it's not something I would care about either. Remake your plots with `-O3`.

Comment: @Zboson: I did not use `-O3` flag. Will rerun experiment after matching compiler version and also with the optimization flag and add an update to question, within next 2 days. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: @Zboson: Experiment rerun after matching compiler versions on host and container for both -- with and without optimization flag -- Results posted in answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of @miraculixx and @Zboson, which helped me understand that the container is not really outperforming the host. The strange results (plot in question) were caused because of the different compiler versions being used on host and container while performing the experiment. When Case A & B are run again after updating to the same version of compiler in both container and host, these are the results:

**Without optimization flag**

[image]

**With optimization flag `-O3`**

[image]

**Observation**

It can be observed that container has same or slightly less performance than host; which makes sense intuitively. (Without optimization there are a couple of discrepancies)

**P.S** Apologies for the misleading question title. I wasn't aware that the performance discrepancy could be because of the different compiler versions until the comments were posted.

Comment: I think the important lesson here is to only discuss performance with optimization enabled. Notice that the the single threaded optimized code is nearly as fast as the unoptimized code with four threads! And four optimized threads is nearly three times faster then four unoptimized threads! I suspect that if you had used optimized for your original plot that you have not seen an unexpected discrepancy since the host used a more recent version of GCC than the container.  Lastly, I would make your plots using scientific notation as it's annoying to count all those zeros.